# Metallic, reflective material not displaying reflections of the World HDRi on EEVEE, how do I fix it?

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine, hdri, reflection

I have enabled screen-space reflections both on render and material options, I have baked indirect lighting, enabled shadows. Then I upgraded the video driver (Intel HD 4400) and yet, this little problem seems to persist: The environment texture doesn't appear on the reflection, only the direct light.

File of the scene in question [image]

The preview of the material, however, seems to be working fine.
[image: Image of Setup]

Comment: I don't think you need an irradiance volume or a reflection sphere to reflect the HDRI - in fact it might be messing with it. Irradiance volume only captures indirect light, and reflection sphere helps with scene reflections - but is not needed for world reflections. I think you might have more success if you deleted them.

Comment: Deleting them unfortunately doesn't change anything. Flat or Smooth shading the cube also doesn't change the environment reflections.

Comment: Hey, I posted an answer. You need to delete the lighting cache after deleting the probes.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked out your .blend file. You don't need an irradiance volume or a reflection sphere to reflect the HDRI - in fact, in this case, it is messing with it. Irradiance volume only captures indirect light, and reflection sphere helps with SCENE reflections - but is not needed for WORLD reflections. It works if you delete them, and then delete the lighting cache - see below:

[image]

If you want to see more of the world reflected, I would also suggest you lower your roughness a bit, but that's up to you and what you want to use it for.

Cheers

Comment: I tried doing that, but it really doesn't solve the problem on my machine, the result remains the same. Could it be something with my video card?

Comment: I 'm not sure. I downloaded your file, deleted the volumes, then the lighting cache, and i'm currently staring at a shiny cube. I changed nothing else. If it's not working on your machine, i'm not sure what's wrong.